# Apply the same compilation command to several source files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have several .cpp files which are built by the same way:

```
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp $(COMPILATION_FLAGS)
file1.o : file1.cpp
    $(CC) -c file1.cpp $(COMPILATION_FLAGS)
file2.o : file2.cpp
    $(CC) -c file2.cpp $(COMPILATION_FLAGS)
```

How can I write this command only once, and then apply it to main, file1 and file2, to exclude code duplication?

Comment: Did you read the GNU Make documentation? I know it is terse in places, but in this case suffix rules should do what you want: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html

Comment: @Colin 't Hart - thanks, but this is used only for backward compatibility. I prefer to use up-to-date way.

Comment: And if you read that page, you would see that it said that GNU Make supports Pattern Rules for this. Did you even read the documentation? And a Google search provided me with the answer.

Comment: @Colin 't Hart - if you don't want to answer - just don't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples

Something like

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

should do what you want.

Why don't you use CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS rather than COMPILATION_FLAGS?